# Can't access rexster interface via browser -- connection refused

Tags: docker, titan, rexster

I have installed the complete "Titan 0.5.2 with Hadoop 2" package in a docker container. I am able to run gremlin, load the sample graph database, and interact with it via the command line, but I'm unable to access the rexster interface via my browser.

I'm using Boot2Docker to interact with the container. I'm attempting to access /graphs using the VM's IP. I've verified that I'm configuring the ports correctly (EXPOSE in the dockerfile, -p in the RUN command) using a simple web server container. But when I try to access the the 8182 port, I get a "Connection Refused" error in my browser. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Get into the container with a `docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash` (or nsenter if you have a docker under 1.3) and debug with the usual `netstat -an` , `route`, `ps -ef`, have a look at `docker logs my_container`, check what `docker events` says when you filter it with --since and --until, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#events and of course check the log files of your software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change "base-uri" in rexster config xml. Check this link for example

https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Troubleshooting#not-using-localhost-to-access-rest-apidog-house